# The demise of Hotmail

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-webapp

We're already seeing some...colorful, fallout due to Microsoft forcing everyone off of the Hotmail interface onto Outlook.com.

Will it be worthwhile to go and close (most) [hotmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) questions as "Too Localized"? I mean, unless Microsoft reverses itself, they're not going to be helpful to any future readers.

Comment: Can't we just leave them as they are. We don't seal books, pre-dating Copernicus´ time do we? We need to make sure that the bot doesn't poke them around anymore. Is that achievable?

Comment: If [Community](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) could be set to ignore tickets with the 'hotmail' tag then that might do the trick indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that any questions that relate to switching back to Hotmail should be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/how-can-i-switch-back-to-hotmail-from-outlook-com).

For any other questions, I would be inclined to agree with you and close them as "Too Localized" (unless of course they could be edited or answered to conform to the new Outlook.com style?)

Comment: yeah but that would mean extensive rewrite of probably question & answer..