# Closing all questions regarding Google Reader

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, obsolete-questions, specific-webapp

Given that Google Reader has been shutdown, I’d say that all questions regarding it should be closed. What say you?

(This should also apply to any and all “dead” web apps, since there can’t be any new answers.)

Comment: Related: [How should questions about defunct services be handled?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1090)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say, yes, they should be closed. However, I don't think we should go out of our way to find them. Just vote to close them when Community pops them to the front page.

I asked a [similar question about Hotmail](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/the-demise-of-hotmail), but that was motivated more by all the people coming here and complaining about the switch to outlook.com.